# Looking up content and exporting results

Tags: python, dictionary, export, function

Please bear with me, Python newbie here.

**EDIT** More generalized question: how can I export something like this:

```
def lookup(x):
  print(something)

lookup(request)
output = open(output, 'w').write(content_of_request)
```

**Original Post**

I have a file with dictionary structure content (`dicx`) where I look up stuff based on input request (`request`). Now, I'd like to export these requested files into a new file, but I'm having trouble doing this... specifically, I don't know how to store `request` into `content` for exporting.

Here's the simplified version of my code:

```
from dicx import list_X

def writefile(x,y,z):
    x = open(y, 'w').write(z)

def lookup(x):
    print(list_X[table_Y]['name_Z1'])
    print(list_X[table_Y]['name_Z2'])

request = raw_input()

if request in list_X:
    lookup(request)
    writefile(output, output, content)
```

I think it gives you  a general idea as to what I'm trying to do, but here's the complete code: http://pastebin.com/HBuihPPF

Comment: Try to generalize your problem. Your code looks very confusing and not consistent.

Comment: Could you also specify the use of your XYZ variables in your write file function?

Comment: @WillCampbell x and y are the output file I am creating, z is the content that I want to be stored in it. So: outputfile = open(output, 'w').write(content)

Comment: I would never write a function like writefile because it only contains a single line of code. From an external point of view it is more confusing in comparision with just using file access. You should also get into the way of giving function parameters like x,y,z a meaningful name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, now I hopefully got you. You should use return values like in other program languages.

```
def lookup(x):
    return something

data = lookup(request)
open(output, 'w').write(data)
```

In Python you can also use [tuples](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) and return multiple variables. But I would only use it where they make sence. Take care of separation of concerns and single responsability of a function/method.

```
def lookup(x):
    return something, whatever

a, b = lookup(request)
```

Comment: Ah, return. I should have thought of that! Thank you so much, I'll play around with it!

Comment: Thats what about almost all programmers go through learning their (first) programming language. :)